# How to assign a user defined parent key on firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to create a parent file using numbers like 1/2/3.... n and save the data on the corresponding number the user is assigned to?
Just a idea I don't know how to make it possible as I am storing value on database using push key or user uid till now

Comment: 0, 1, 2, etc, sounds like an array, which is actually possible in Firebase. But more convenient would be to store user data under their UIDs or under the pushed IDs for other data.

Comment: How to store user data in array? @AlexMamo